# Difference event setCurrentScreen vs logScreenView in FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to add event to my firebase application but confused between the two. Can anybody guide which one to use and when.

There is also a link which says setCurrentScreen is deprecated. But it still shows in my library. Kindly guide here also.

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true, that `setCurrentScreen` is deprecated. You need to use `logEvent` method. Find more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens).